# cakephp contains condition date filter or limit records

Tags: mysql, cakephp, contain

In my find, I'm using contain with a condition to get the current schedule, as shown:

```
    $this->request->data = $this->Employee->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Employee.emp_appserial' => $id),
        'contain' => array(
            'Schedule' => array(
                'conditions' => array('ho_valid <=' => date('Y-m-d'), 'ho_status' => 1)
            )
        )
    ));
```

It works fine, but when the conditions is met for more than one record I need only the one closer to now.

I'm aware is more of a sql question, but I need the filter to fit the contain condition format.

Can you help?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Dont u get the first record? what do you mean by closer to now ?

Comment: @Moyed Ansari. I'm getting 2 records that meet the criteria ho_valid <=' => date('Y-m-d'); I only need the one closer to now (date('Y-m-d')) thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to add order by on the date and apply limit so that you can achieve latest first record

```
 $this->request->data = $this->Employee->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Employee.emp_appserial' => $id),
        'contain' => array(
            'Schedule' => array(
                'conditions' => array('ho_valid <=' => date('Y-m-d'), 'ho_status' => 1),
                'order' => 'ho_valid'
                'limit' => 1
            )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you @Moyed Ansari; just had to add 'desc' to order to get the latest closest to now. I really appreciate your help. :-)